# compile more than one turtle scripts in the same directory

Tags: haskell-turtle

while I can use several turtle scripts in the same directory
(have eg. pretty.hs and srv.hs interpreted), I learned that I can have
only have one of them compiled eg. with

```
ghc -no-user-package-db -package-db .cabal-sandbox/*-packages.conf.d -O2 -threaded -outputdir=. -o srv srv.hs
```

as this implicitly builds Main.o and Main.hi as well, and and srv and pretty would
need two different object files, obviously.

What's the story of Turtle and the Main module anyway: wouldn't it
have been nicer, if one could use (and thus choose) a module name, like so

```
Module Whatever
import Turtle
```

I tried to compile the .o files separatly, but with no luck:

```
$ ghc -no-user-package-db -package-db .cabal-sandbox/*-packages.conf.d -O2 -threaded -outputdir=. -c -o MainPretty.o pretty.hs
```

no complaints so far, but then:

```
$ ghc -no-user-package-db -package-db .cabal-sandbox/*-packages.conf.d -O2 -threaded -outputdir=. -o pretty MainPretty.o

MainPretty.o: In function `rdyO_info':
(.text+0x40e): undefined reference to `transzuGZZTjP9K5WFq01xC9BAGQpF_ControlziMonadziIOziClass_zdfMonadIOIO_closure'
MainPretty.o: In function `rdyQ_info':
(.text+0x4d6): undefined reference to `transzuGZZTjP9K5WFq01xC9BAGQpF_ControlziMonadziIOziClass_zdfMonadIOIO_closure'
MainPretty.o: In function `cfxy_info':
(.text+0x712): undefined reference to `optpazuFpNJ7fLofFNEy3rK4ZZnBoD_OptionsziApplicativeziTypes_AltP_con_info'
MainPretty.o: In function `cfxy_info':
(.text+0x72e): undefined reference to `systezu0e3pMPmZZzzix21iFp2U03Lc_FilesystemziPathziRules_posixFromText_closure'
MainPretty.o: In function `cfyR_info':
(.text+0x92a): undefined reference to `optpazuFpNJ7fLofFNEy3rK4ZZnBoD_OptionsziApplicativeziTypes_AltP_con_info'
```

and so on...

Is it possible nevertheless to compile two different turtle scripts in the same dir? how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, to answer my own question: I saw that I just have to remove these Main.o/Main.hi files after compiling (to have different one created anew then),
like so:

```
ghc -no-user-package-db -package-db .cabal-sandbox/*-packages.conf.d -O2 -threaded -outputdir=. -o pretty pretty.hs
rm -f Main.o Main.hi
```

Sorry for the noise

Comment: If you give `ghc` the ` -fforce-recomp ` flag it will get rid of these files before attempting to compile.